# Date giving exception in US server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I am getting a date string from the javascript and converting that to Datetime and save that to the database.

But in the Indian server my code working fine. But when I upload my code to US based server it's giving exception. Is there any common way to make my code runnable to all the server.

My code is like below

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool submitDate( string date ) // format is dd-mm-yyyy 20-01-2011
 {
    DateTime DOBdate = DateTime.Now;
    double age = 0.0;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(date , out DOBdate))
    {
            age = (DateTime.Now - DOBdate).Days / 365;
    }

      dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DOBdate); 
}
```

Please help me.

the exception which is showing is
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: Why is your string in a regional, ambiguous format? Try `yyyymmdd`. Or using a date in the first place, rather than a string. Are you letting people type this stuff in by hand? Why?

Comment: I am using datepicker to pick the date and sent that to the server in the function.

Comment: So why on earth does your datepicker pass a string in the format dd-mm-yyyy? This is obviously not going to work on a US server, which is going to expect mm-dd-yyyy. There is no 20th month, hence the overflow. Thankfully this didn't happen on the 10th, in which case you would have just saved terribly incorrect data with no error at all.

Comment: Using non-regional formats is a good idea due to the multinational nature of the internet.  However as this is the case the server should also be using non-regional formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use TryParseExact, I guess the default datetime format of the server is not dd-mm-yyyy. And you should handle the if of the parse function:

```
public static bool submitDate( string date ) // format is dd-mm-yyyy 20-01-2011
{
    DateTime DOBdate = DateTime.Now;
    double age = 0.0;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date , {"dd-MM-yyyy"}, 
                          null,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out DOBdate))
    {
         age = (DateTime.Now - DOBdate).Days / 365;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle this case!
    }

    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DOBdate); 
 }
```

BTW your age function is not a realy good indication of the age. The older your person, the more faulty it gets.

Comment: "the more faulty it gets" Is "it" referring to the person or the function? Both are probably valid in my experience.

Comment: Funny.

But yeah if you don't take into account leap years, you will end up getting the age wrong (by a matter of days, but you could be borderline on the birth date).